# Passing a PHP variable to another page via jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

EDIT: I can put the question in a shorter way that perhaps focuses more closely on the real problem:

Is there a way to keep PHP Sockets alive over multiple pages? That is, can I store the connection (the socket object) in any way?

I want to save a socket connection between two PHP pages where the other page is loaded via jQuery ajax. I tried it with sessions and so far got this on my main page:

```
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
$res = socket_connect($sock, $host, $port);
session_start();
$_SESSION['sock'] = $sock;
```

I then load a page with jQuery:

```
$("#" + in_name + "_holder").load("set_setpoint.php", {name:in_name, value:in_value});
```

And in set_setpoints.php:

```
session_start();     
require_once("sock_funcs.php");    
echo $_SESSION['sock'];
```

I only get '0', but what I should get is something like "Resource id #xxx". Maybe sessions is the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass resources between pages.

see
[PHP pfsockopen in a session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213464/php-pfsockopen-in-a-session)

Comment: So you mean that i need to establish a new tcp connection everytime the other page is loaded? Im new to php but seems so impossibly akward

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use COOKIE to save your value and then access using CLIENT anywhere you want.

**1**

> $_COOKIE["socketNo"] = "somevalue";

Access it like

> $_COOKIE["socketNo"];

Make sure the cookie is accessible.

**2**

You can pass the data as a query-string to the URL that is used on AJAX call and retrieve it in your script.

> $("#" + in_name + "_holder").load("set_setpoint.php?socketNo=", {name:in_name, value:in_value});

in set_setpoints.php

> $sock = $_GET["socketNo"];

Comment: Have you gotten this to work? For me it doesnt work with resources, only strings

Answer (score 0):

You can use GET or POST to pass the content, or you can set a cookied encoded and share the content between the two applications.

Answer (score 0):

just try $.get(); in jquery,,

for ur question $.get() or $.post();

if u use $.get(); then u can understand how this parrameter run if any doubt ask me dude..